# passing parameter to function error

Tags: r

when I call sapply with plink I get this error

argument is missing, with no default

any ideas to get it to work?

```
plink = function(post, original_predictor1,original_predictor2){
  with(post,
      result = parameter_vector1*original_predictor1 + parameter_vector2*original_predictor2
  )
  return(result)
}

post = data.frame(parameter_vector1 = c(1,2),parameter_vector2 = c(9,5))
original_predictor1 = c(1,2) #original predictor variable x in y = beata*x
original_predictor2 = c(10,20) #original predictor variable x in y = beata*x
pred.raw = sapply(1:2, function(i) plink(original_predictor1[i],original_predictor2[i]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big problem is that you're not passing `post` to your `plink` function as the first parameter. Also it's not a good idea to use `=` to create variables inside the `with()` function since those are interpreted as named parameters. This should work

```
plink = function(post, original_predictor1, original_predictor2){
  result <- with(post, parameter_vector1*original_predictor1 + parameter_vector2*original_predictor2
  )
  return(result)
}

post = data.frame(parameter_vector1 = c(1,2),parameter_vector2 = c(9,5))
original_predictor1 = c(1,2) #original predictor variable x in y = beata*x
original_predictor2 = c(10,20) #original predictor variable x in y = beata*x
pred.raw = sapply(1:2, function(i) plink(post, original_predictor1[i],original_predictor2[i]))
```